# Is there any convenient way of creating such an iOS button

Tags: ios, user-interface

The buttons at the bottom of the following images (**the middle one**) , **x** and **search** are really cool. Is there any good way to do that?  I tried to put two buttons in one table cell  as custom buttons but too ugly, feel so shame to put it over here. :/

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Got two downvote in 2s, wow~

Comment: Is there anyone can tell me what is wrong with such a question?

Comment: Your question is very general.  Typically 'please write some code for me' questions are closed.  You should post the code you've tried that isn't working.

Comment: @andorov Sometimes it is not all about the code/programming, instead , it could be suggesting a framework, a thought. Statckoverflow is becoming a place of criticizing other people without a moment of thinking. That is also why many people left and not be willing to help. Hope stackoverflow people can see this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here you have bro its just simple 2 button in the bottom of the view 
[image]

And you will get this result

[image]

Comment: I never thought it could be as simple like this. That is pretty straight forward. Those people just down vote this question for nothing... Stackoverflow is ....

Comment: yeah something ppl can be a lil bit harsh but if you just do this you could get the view as you wanted it! @Ben